# Abbreviation for 'formatting'?

Tags: abbreviations

I can't find the abbreviation for the word **formatting** in the sense of formatting text or code.

I'd like to shorten commit changes on Github instead of always typing or copying the word *formatting.* Is there any abbreviation for this instead of `fmt` in the sense of formatting text or code? `fmt` might do, but it's connoted with *format,* not *formatting.* Is there something else?

Comment: Where do you need the abbreviation? Would _fmtg_ work?

Comment: IMO for your specific use-case you should be spelling "formatting" out.  It's more important that your commit readers can clearly understand what you mean than saving 6 characters' worth of typing (which roughly only translates to 1 second of saved time typing anyway).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use *fmtg* as an abbreviation for formatting.

Comment: While it does answer the OP, it is not structured very well for an official answer. It would help if you formatted it to help other people that may come across the post. Maybe some reasoning as to how you can to the suggestion? Our posts/answers are here to help all, not just one :)